# Declaring the datasource of another formBox, by the currently selected listBox item

Tags: c#, winforms

Apologies if this has been asked already,

I want to know how to declare the datasource of a textbox or a listbox by the currently selected listBox object.

So box 1 has the list of items, and each selection prints to the next box with more information about them (`ItemInfo`)

Here is my code that I'm working with:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != null)
            {
                listBox2.DataSource = ItemStorage._?_?_?_?_(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
        }

public class ItemObject
        {
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public string ItemInfo { get; set; }

            public ItemObject(string itemName, string itemInfo)
            {
                ItemName = itemName;
                ItemInfo = itemInfo;
            }


             public override string ToString()
            {
                return ItemName;
            }

        }
```

The list name is `ItemStorage` and the element I want to print to the other box is `ItemInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer I was looking for:

Instead of using a listBox, I opted for a richTextBox and this is the code I used:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != null)
        {
            try { var Information = ((ItemObject)listBox1.SelectedItem).ItemInfo;
                richTextBox2.Text = Information;
            }
            catch( Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

This provided me with only getting the information from the selected item I wanted to have, so my listbox has a full total of all the items, while the selection only shows me the information from the one ive selected.